# Cannot get document.GetElementById working right

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I am trying to call a javascript function from onClick event of an asp server button. I have this button and a label in an update panel.

In aspx:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
       <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
            style="z-index: 1; left: 49px; top: 119px; position: absolute; height: 26px;" Text="Button" 
            onclick="Button1_Click"/>
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="l1" 
            style="position:absolute; top: 123px; left: 127px;"></asp:Label>
       </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Button), "me", "me()", true);
}
```

Javascript in aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function me()
{
   document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').value="clicked";
}
</script>
```

All I am trying to do is on button click the label's value should be changed to 'clicked', which isn't happening and no error as well in firebug. Where am I wrong in the me( )?

P.S: I am doing this to learn calling a javascript function from code behind. So any optimizations to the code are also welcome. (I actually have much lot of code to implement in the JS function later so appropriate suggestions please)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I remember the Label control is rendered as a `<div>` or `<span>` (can't remember exactly), not a text input field. So you should be setting its `innerHTML` property not the `value`:

```
document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>').innerHTML = 'clicked';
```

or simply do it on the server side instead of registering clientside callbacks:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Label1.Text = "clicked";
}
```

---

UPDATE:

As requested in the comments section here's how you could pass parameters to the clientside callback from the server:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string param1 = ...
    double param2 = ...
    int param3 = ...
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
        this, 
        typeof(Button), 
        "me", 
        string.Format("me({0})", serializer.Serialize(new { param1 = param1, param2 = param2, param3 = param3 })), 
        true
    );
}
```

and your callback:

```
function me(values) {
    // you could use values.param1, values.param2, values.param3, ... here
}
```

Comment: That works great. I jst need to wait for 8 mins to accept answer. Actually my requirement is this: I have a button in a update panel and a google map out side it. I am performing some operation in code behind on button click and passing to values to a javascript function in .aspx. This javascript function then displays the values on the maps as per my need. I just transfered that into this example. I am unable to do this in my maps case. Any solution for that?

Comment: @Cdeez, yes, you could easily pass parameters to the callback from the server. I have updated my answer to illustrate this. You could also pass entire complex object graphs.